# Is EnsureChildControls() in OnLoad a bit of a code smell?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, controls

I'm fluffing around with validators for some custom `CompositeControls` at the moment, and in order to get the server-side validation working I need to do the following:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    EnsureChildControls();
    base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

I've not fully grasped the ASP.NET page lifecycle yet, and am wondering if this is a bit of an ASP smell in general, or is it OK?

(The reason I need to call `EnsureChildControls()` is because my validators are dynamically added in `CreateChildControls()`, but it seems the server-side validation is performed before `CreateChildControls()` is naturally called, and hence before I've actually created any validators.  So I'm calling `EnsureChildControls()` to force them to exist.)

Comment: Asp.net is a code smell:) use MVC

Comment: Ha, I wish :-)  This all has to fit inside SharePoint 2007, which doesn't play so nice with ASP MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Say your routine that adds validators is CrateValidators()

I would suggest you move this to Page_Init and LoadViewState basically

```
bool _doCreateValidators=false;
void OnPageInit(sender,args){
    if(_doCreateValidators){
        CreateValidators();
    }
}

protected override void LoadViewState(StateBag savedState){
       CreateValidators();
       _doCreateValidators = false;
       base.LoadViewState(savedState);
}
```